# Populate MySQL table with dummy data using times from another table

Tags: mysql, populate

I have one table filled with timestamps, and upon creating another table I want to fill it with zero values for each of those timestamps. For instance:

```
Timestamps table
Timestamps |
-----------|
2014-07-01 |
2014-07-02 |
2014-07-03 |
2014-07-04 |
2014-07-05 |
2014-07-06 |
```

And I want to create a second table like this:

```
Table 2
Timestamps | Values
-----------|--------
2014-07-01 | 0
2014-07-02 | 0
2014-07-03 | 0
2014-07-04 | 0
2014-07-05 | 0
2014-07-06 | 0
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table new_table as
select t.*, 0 as values
from your_table t;
```

Simple as that.